# Vim open a certain size but return to terminal window size when closed

Tags: vimrc

so my terminal window size on MAC OS is 100 columns and 30 rows.

When I open `vim` like this `vim filename.txt` I want the size to open to whatever size is specified in `.vimrc` (this works).

The size in my `.vimrc` is 200 columns and 40 rows. When I quit vim with `:q` I want the size of the window to go back to the terminal size (100 columns and 30 rows) but it remains 200 columns and 40 rows. Is there a way to go back to 100 coulmns and 30 rows automatically when `vim` closes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an autocmd with the event `VimLeave` to reset `lines` and `columns` before Vim closes. Add the following to your `vimrc`:

```
augroup term_size
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimLeave * set columns=100 lines=30
augroup END
```

The autocmd is executed once when Vim is about to exit and resets `colums` and `lines`.

I use a autocmd-group to prevent multiple definition of the autocmd when the `vimrc` is sourced multiple times (e.g. during testing Vim setup). The `autocmd!` clears the group before the autocmd for `VimLeave` is defined. See `:help autocmd-groups`.